# Radio button selection in angular

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I am working on radio buttons in angular. I am able to populate radio button values from server but it seems that I am missing such small thing to work on them properly.

HTML >>

```
 <label data-ng-repeat="milestoneType in question">
      <input type="radio" name="milestoneType" data-ng-model="milestoneType.Id" data-ng-value="true" data-ng-change="getMilestoneType(milestoneType.Id)" />
           {{milestoneType.Type}}
 </label><br />
```

Script Code >>

```
$scope.populateType();

$scope.populateType = function() {

  $http.get(service_url + "Project/GetMilestoneType", {
      params: {
        "Id": 0
      }
    })
    .success(function(response) {
      if (response.length < 1) {
        $('#divErrorGrid').show();

      } else {
        $('#divErrorGrid').hide();
        $scope.question = response;

      }
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      fnSuccessModal("Error in Load", "Error");
    });
}

$scope.getMilestoneType = function(milestoneType) {

  console.log(milestoneType);
  if (milestoneType== "1") {

    $scope.loadProjectMilestones();
  } else if (milestoneType== "2")

    $scope.loadCategoryMilestones();
}
```

List returned by Server :

```
Id  Title
2    Project
3    Category
```

Now I simply want to get the functionality work whenever user will change the radio button selection on interface. Whenever user will select "Project" radio button then loadProjectMilestones function will be called and if "Category" radio button is selected then loadCategoryMilestones function will be called. And Based on this selection , functionality will work.

In other way, I just want that if I select Project radio button then MilestoneType value should get 2 and if I select Category radio button then the value should be 3 (as in the list above).

But I am not able to get the functionality work properly.

Comment: Do you get any errors or what happens when you select the radio buttons ?

Comment: what is `MilestoneType`? where it is declared?

Comment: @van No I am not getting any error.I just want that if I select Project radio button then MilestoneType value should get 2 and if I select Category radio button then the value should be 3 (as in the list above)

Comment: You are getting `console.log(MilestoneType);`?? Is `MilestoneType` string value???

Comment: As @ParthTrivedi asked, can you tell us what do you get on console.log ?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I am getting value as true.. but I want it should get value as "1" or "2"...bcz on basis of its value my functionality will work.

Comment: Can you provide what are you getting in `milestoneType in question` `JSON`??

Comment: try to remove `data-ng-value="true"`